# Encountered Segmentation fault in simple OpenCV code

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake, mingw

## Tools

- Platform : 64-bit Windows
- Compiler chain: mingw with Qt
- Make system: CMake
- Libraries: C++ 11, OpenCV 4, Qt 5

## Problem (Updated)

The following simple program segment should compile and display the generated image in OpenCV. However, it always SIGSEGVs in DEBUG mode only(Backtrace at the end). However, it works just fine in RELEASE mode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;

void testOPENCV()
{
   cv::Mat output(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255,0,100));
   cv::namedWindow( "Test", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   cv::imshow("Test",output);
   cv::waitKey(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   testOPENCV();
   return 0;
}
```

I have a CMake script that builds only the required OpenCV modules and links these to the dependencies. The relevant part:

```
build_external_project(opencv "https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git" "4.2.0" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${THIRDPARTY_INSTALLFOLDER} - DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${THIRDPARTY_BUILDTYPE} -DBUILD_LIST=core,imgproc,imgcodecs,highgui")

target_link_libraries(OpenVideo ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The binary can be run with no missing dll errors. Dependency walker also indicates the same.

Here is the backtrace:

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: "This simple program segment should compile", no, it shouldn't. I don't see a `main()`. I don't see appropriate header files getting `#include`d. Just because your program crashes with a backtrace here doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The bug could be anywhere in your code. Which is why stackoverflow.com's [help] gives you instructions for creating a [mre] so that anyone can cut/paste the code ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce your problem. You did not follow these instructions, and because of that it's unlikely that anyone can help you.

Comment: It would be also helpful to post your .pro file

Comment: Are you inserting breakpoints in your lines before running the code?

Comment: @ManjunathReddy I tested this code in Visual Studio, opencv 3.4.5, in debug and release with no problems. Check your opencv installation for debug mode. there might be an error there

Answer (score 2):

Given that OpenCV works fine in Release mode, I suggest rebuilding the Debug version of the library.

**Previous answer**:

There are a few potential problems with your code:

- Using Qt is unnecessary on this example and it adds a complexity that you don't need right now. Remove it from the project and its libraries on the link instruction in the CMake script. Later, you can bring it back to see if it causes of the crash. Right now you need to pinpoint if the problem is in OpenCV or Qt.
- An image can only be displayed on a window if `cv::waitKey()` is invoked;
- The directory separator on Windows is usually `\\` and not `/`;

This is the full source code to test your OpenCV build:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{
   std::string file_name("C:\\Images\\1.jpg");
   cv::Mat original_image = cv::imread(file_name, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
   if (original_image.empty())
   {
       std::cout << "!!! image not found" << std::endl;
       return -1;
   }

   cv::imshow( "Display window", original_image ); 
   cv::waitKey(0);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's make sure it's not the basics that are crippling your development.

Comment: The problem is definitely with OpenCV as indicated in the updated question.

Comment: I'm glad that you updated the question taking my recommendations into consideration. Nevertheless, it's good taste to up vote the answers that helped you fine tune the question as well. I believe that you might not have the Debug version of OpenCV built correctly since the Release version works fine.

Comment: Note the compiler is: MinGW.  

MinGW uses a "/" directory delimiter by default.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to check here.

First, where do the OpenCV library come from? Is it compiled for your CPU? Looks like it crashed in AVX instructions. Might be that CPU does not support them.

Second, not obvious at all, happened to me with `.png` files. Same segfault during runtime. Turned out that OpenCV was built without `png` support. Please check if your OpenCV built with `-DWITH_JPEG=ON`.

Comment: Yes, the OpenCV is compiled for my CPU(64 bit Intel Xeon E2146G). Please note that the problem seems to be independent of the type of image since displaying a generated matrix also fails.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

You forgot to create window

```
namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to karlphillips answer: Deubg and Release behave quite differently on Windows than on Linux (due to runtime selection).

Especially if you link against release libraries on Windows but your libs or executable are being built in debug. If they use different runtimes you will be very likely run into issues and segfaults. So check the flags of both projects (typical culprits are flags like multithreading (debug) being present on one but not the other).